# How to correct the tableview section header frame according to the orientation / UITableView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with grouped style - and I have a custom header view:

```
+ (UIView *) viewForHeaderWithText: (NSString*) title
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        UIView *viewHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 20.0f);
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        label.text = title;
        if (!IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
            label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        [viewHeader addSubview:label];
        return viewHeader;
    }
}
```

So the section header width frame is fixed.

but For different orientation and way of presenting the UITableViewController the cell width (iOS6) is changed - as u can see on the screenshots. But I need to make offset for the section title and cell equal.

Now I have:

[image] [image]

What I need:

[image]

I tried to change the cell width - but not solve this.. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to impelement this below uitableView delegate method:-

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```